# Generate collections for pages and posts

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

currently i am not able to generate two different collections of pages with assemble.
On the one hand i want to generate my pages, which are displayed in the main navigation - On the other side i want to generate my blog posts, with categories and tags - how can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

My grunt configuration looks like below

```
        assemble: {
        options: {
            sitename: '<%= site.variables.sitename %>',
            plugins: ['permalinks'],
            assets: '<%= site.paths.src %>/assets',
            partials: ['<%= site.paths.src %>/partials/*.hbs'],
            helpers: ['<%= site.paths.src %>/helpers/helper-*.js'],
            layout: 'default.hbs',
            layoutdir: '<%= site.paths.src %>/layouts',
            data: ['<%= site.paths.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}'],
            collections: [{
                name: 'post',
                sortby: 'posted',
                sortorder: 'descending'
            }]
        },
        posts: {
            files: [{
                cwd: '<%= site.paths.src %>/content/',
                dest: '<%= site.paths.dist %>',
                expand: true,
                src: ['**/*.{md,hbs}', '!_pages/**/*.{md,hbs}']
            }, {
                cwd: '<%= site.paths.src %>/content/_pages/',
                dest: '<%= site.paths.dist %>',
                expand: true,
                src: '**/*.{md,hbs}'
            }]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v0.4.x the collections specify the types of collections you want to generate from the pages going through and their front-matter. You'll have to add front-matter to your `posts` like:

```
---
posts:
 - true
posted: 10-SEP-2014
---
```

However, the collection sorting isn't smart enough to know how to sort dates property. You might be able to add an actual date object as `posted` or just make it the order you want.

Then to use the `posts` collection, you could do `{{#each this.posts}}` in handlebars. That would give you all the pages that have `posts` defined in the front-matter. There might be some other things that need to be added in the templates, but I'm not thinking of them off the top of my head.

If you have a repo I can take a look at, it might be easier to help out.

Comment: It would be great if you could on my repository. The problem is, that is currently a private repository. Have you a contact possibility outside from stackoverflow? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @xyNNN sure, send me an email at brian . woodward @ gmail . com